# C++ std::cout printing wierd characters when I enclose a string with single quotations

Tags: c++, cout

when I tried `std::cout << ', ';` I got `11296`, I know that I should've enclosed it with `", "`, but why do I get the number?

Comment: Those are not "brackets".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got two characters in single quotes (comma and space).
The value of such multicharacter literals depends on your compiler etc.

In this case, the ASCII values are 44 and 32, and

```
11296 = 44 * 256 + 32
```

ie. both bytes together understood as 16bit integer

Answer (score 1):

According to the standard (**N4296, 2.13.3 Character literals**, emphasis mine):

> An
>   ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a multicharacter literal. **A multicharacter
>   literal**, or an ordinary character literal containing a single c-char not representable in the execution character
>   set, **is conditionally-supported, has type int, and has an implementation-defined value**.

"*Conditionally-supported*" is (1.3.5)

> program construct that an implementation is not required to support